# Summing multiple float values into a new float (Double values)

Tags: objective-c, ios, double

How can I sum multiple doubleValues into a new double? At the moment I have tried like this:

```
double sum = doubleWantToSum1 + doubleWantToSum2 + doubleWantToSum; //etc...
```

And further, I want to use the result for this equation in

```
double tooMuch = sum - 100;
```

Which I want to return 100 minus the total value of my floats. At the moment the only thing this does is  to output doubleWantToSum1 - 100. I believe the answer to this rediciously simple, but since I could not find anything on the internet about this I would love it if one of you guys told me.

**EDIT, ADDED CODE**
Note, I know this is poor and probably uneffective.

```
//Nummerformatterere - Kinda unødvendig
NSNumberFormatter *fmt1  =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //Temp
NSNumberFormatter *fmt2  =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //Methane
NSNumberFormatter *fmt3  =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //Ethane
NSNumberFormatter *fmt4  =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //Propane
NSNumberFormatter *fmt5  =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //n-butane
NSNumberFormatter *fmt6  =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //i-butane
NSNumberFormatter *fmt7  =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //n-petane
NSNumberFormatter *fmt8  =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //i-petane
NSNumberFormatter *fmt9  =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //n-hexane
NSNumberFormatter *fmt10 =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //nitrogen
NSNumberFormatter *fmt11 =  [NSNumberFormatter new]; //oxygen

//Float for å få textfieldsene til nummer
double temprature = [fmt1  numberFromString: tempratureText.text].doubleValue;
double methane    = [fmt2  numberFromString: methaneText.text   ].doubleValue;
double ethane     = [fmt3  numberFromString: ethaneText.text    ].doubleValue;
double propane    = [fmt4  numberFromString: propaneText.text   ].doubleValue;
double nbutane    = [fmt5  numberFromString: nbutaneText.text   ].doubleValue;
double ibutane    = [fmt6  numberFromString: ibutaneText.text   ].doubleValue;
double npetane    = [fmt7  numberFromString: npetaneText.text   ].doubleValue;
double ipetane    = [fmt8  numberFromString: ipetaneText.text   ].doubleValue;
double nhexane    = [fmt9  numberFromString: nhexaneText.text   ].doubleValue;
double nitrogen   = [fmt10 numberFromString: nitrogenText.text  ].doubleValue;
double oxygen     = [fmt11 numberFromString: oxygenText.text    ].doubleValue;

//Floats og formatters for underflow, overflow
double sum = (methane + ethane + propane + nbutane + ibutane + npetane + ipetane + nhexane + nitrogen + oxygen);
double overflowPart = 100 - sum;
double underflowPart = sum - 100;

NSNumber *underFlow = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithDouble:underflowPart];
NSNumberFormatter *underFlowResult = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
underFlowResult.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
[underFlowResult setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[underFlowResult setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSString *formattedUnderFlow = [underFlowResult stringFromNumber:(NSNumber*)underFlow];

NSNumber *overFlow = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithDouble:underflowPart];
NSNumberFormatter *overFlowResult = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
overFlowResult.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
[overFlowResult setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[overFlowResult setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSString *formattedOverFlow = [overFlowResult stringFromNumber:(NSNumber*)overFlow];

//Floats for variabler til ligningen
double Xi = 1;
double Mi = 2;
double Vi = 3;
double Vc = 4;

//Ligningen for å regne ut density
double over1 = Xi * Mi;
double under1 = Xi * Vi - Vc;

//=RESULT=
double result =  over1 / under1;

/*----------STREK FORDI DET ER CHILL OG JEG ER FERDIG MED FLOATER----------*/

NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"D = %f", result];
NSString *overflowString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Total %@ greater than 100 %", formattedOverFlow ];
NSString *underflowString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Total %@ less than 100 %", formattedUnderFlow];

/*----------STREK FORDI DET ER CHILL OG JEG ER FERDIG MED STRINGS----------*/
/*
if (temprature == 0 || methane == 0 || ethane == 0 || propane == 0 || nbutane == 0 || ibutane == 0 || oxygen == 0 || npetane == 0 || ipetane == 0 || nhexane == 0 || nitrogen == 0)
{
    outputText.text = @"Please enter all values";
} */
if (underflowPart == 100)
{
    outputText.text = @"Start by entering values above";
}
if (sum == 100)
{
    outputText.text = resultString;
}

if (sum > 100)
{
    outputText.text = overflowString;
}

if (sum < 100)
{
    outputText.text = underflowString;
}
/*----------STREK FORDI DET ER CHILL OG JEG ER FERDIG MED 'if'----------*/
```

Comment: What are the values of `doubleWantToSum1`, `doubleWantToSum2`, etc., when you get the wrong answer?  What is the value of `sum`?

Comment: If you're saying that `tooMuch` is always returning `doubleWantToSum1 - 100` then I'd check the other `doubleWantToSum` values - they would be zero in this case and somewhere in your code you haven't defined them properly.

Comment: @robmayoff added full code including how I define my numbers.

Comment: Log the actual values of the individual addends (`methane`, `ethane`, etc.) when you get the wrong result and paste them into your question.

Comment: OH, My bad, I should really mention this. The text fields got XIB spaceholders with values. The log shows (for methane) 90 every time. I will reset those, and take a further look.

Comment: Well, that fixed it. Thanks for the headsup on me being bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has not yet been explicitly said in the comments that the way you are summing the numbers in your code is correct. What the comments are implying is that the numbers you are summing are wrong, and you should log them to see what they are.

As well, you could save some code (eliminate your number formatters) by using:

```
double temprature = [tempratureText.text doubleValue];
```

instead of

```
double temprature = [fmt1  numberFromString: tempratureText.text].doubleValue;
```

Comment: Yeah, this kinda fixed it aswell. Turns out my problem was me having XIB placeholders. It also seems like the way im summing my numbers atm is correct (?)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, the way you were summing is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how large (how much precision) the numbers have that you are adding.  In order to get around this, you can use [NSDecimalNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which will hold up to 38 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: Precision is not very important here, as im working with round numbers between 0 and 100. As said below, I want to know how to add multiple variables together.